# Piping output from a python script to a remote machine?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I have a python script that output/prints a large array (50MB in size) to the screen. This script is running on `machineA`. Is it at all possible to 'pipe' this output to `machineB`, where it will be processed?

I know I can save the output in a file on `machineA` and then send the file to `machineB`. I was just wondering if it is possible to do so without having to save the data first to a file (on `machineA`).

Any solutions (python, bash shell, other ideas) will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a work for `nc` (netcat)... on `machineB` you do

```
nc -l 12345 | processing_program
```

This command will start netcat in "listen mode" waiting for a connection. Once the connection is established what is coming from the network will be sent to stdout and what is sent to stdin will be sent back to whoever connected.

After that you go on `machineA` and run

```
generating_program | nc machineB 12345
```

this will instruct netcat to start a connection to `machineB` (port 12345) and send whatever it gets from stdin over the wire. Whatever comes back from that connection is sent to standard output.

Comment: Your answer is better (no need for passwords, or for running a service).

Comment: 6502: thank you. can `machineB` be listening to 20 machines at the same time? also, must I actively 'open the listening port' on `machineB`?

Comment: With that command `machineB` will be listening to whoever connects (so this is of course not secure at all... anyone on the internet without any authentication can send data to `processing_program` using `machineB` if that machine can be reached!). `nc` terminates once the client closes the connection so you will eventually need to rerun the command in a loop. If for "opening the listening port" you mean making an hole in your firewall or defining a virtual server path in your router the answer is yes. `nc` simply does a TCP listen on the specified port.

Answer (score 1):

With the [Netcat tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) you may easily pipe data from one machine to another.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it on different levels - here are a few options

1. use ssh to pipe 
         myprog | ssh remotemachine myotherprog
2. use nfs (if going to a file
3. use netcat (nc)
4. use something like thrift

It depends on how solid & permanent the solution needs to be

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something along the lines of

```
myPythonScript | ssh user@machine "sh -c 'cat >myfile.txt'"
```

WARNING: pulled entirely out of my head and untested!

Answer (score 1):

On machineA:

```
python script-on-machineA.py --options | ssh machineB tee /file/on/machine/B.txt
```

Alternatively, on machineB:

```
ssh machineA python /path/to/script-on-machineA.py --options | cat > /file/on/machine/B.txt
```

Comment: This would work well, since I can easily SSH between the machines.